# pyenv trying to install files globally instead of locally

Tags: python, pyspark, pip, databricks, pyenv

I created a new virtual environment via this command

```
python3 -m venv test_v4
```

I check that in my activate file that this config is correct

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test-job/test_v4
```

I then check correct pip is in fact activated

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test-job/test_v4/bin/pip
```

But when I run the pip install  with multiple requirements file I get this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
       command: /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python3.7 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cs/mqdnkvqx3ml4dglkn7q6_tp80000gp/T/pip-resolver-0honk05v/databricks-connect/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cs/mqdnkvqx3ml4dglkn7q6_tp80000gp/T/pip-resolver-0honk05v/databricks-connect/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/cs/mqdnkvqx3ml4dglkn7q6_tp80000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-pxswo4sk
           cwd: /private/var/folders/cs/mqdnkvqx3ml4dglkn7q6_tp80000gp/T/pip-resolver-0honk05v/databricks-connect/
      Complete output (1 lines):
      Found conflicting `pyspark` installation at /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark. Please uninstall this with `pip uninstall pyspark` before installing databricks-connect.
```

Just by looking at the error message I ahve a question. Is "pip install" trying to access globally what is in 3.7.10? I was expecting to see pip trying to store files in this folder structure.

```
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/test_v4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark
```

or atleast

```
/Users/srinivaspachari/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/test_v4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark
```

The reason is this is whole point of creating a virtual environment. Is my understanding correct? Also if anyone can tell me how to fix this issue that will be great.

I even tried

```
pip uninstall pyspark
```

I get this error messaage

```
WARNING: Skipping pyspark as it is not installed.
```

Comment: Try creating the environment with Pycharm. When you create a new project it asks you for the new environment.

Comment: Using venv I've always done the following to install to venv: 
1. python3 -m venv .venv 
2. source .venv/bin/activate 
3. python3 -m pip install <module name>

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys, but I fixed the issue by uninstalling pyspark in my local and then installing all the packages. I am not sure why the venv has any requirement to what is installed in my local machine (this defeats the purpose of having a virtual environment)